# I have an error 403 in php contact form in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded my site in AWS S3.
I have 2 contact forms (They are not working, it appears to have a 403 error).
*Error: 403 https://odontoluan.mx/forms/contact.php*
I uploaded my site in other bluehost server trial and they are working fine, I receive the emails correctly. I think I have to add more permisions but seems that they are not working.
I will hide my ID, Sid and Resourse for protection

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyMYPOLICE",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "(MYPUBLICID)",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYSITE.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried adding a new statement with the specific file but still not working

The bad site: odontoluan.mx |
The site working fine: plusmarketing.mx

Greetings!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? First of all AWS S3 is only an object storage service. It can serve static files as web pages, but cannot interpret PHP, so where is your PHP interpreter running? Second - the IAM policy would be possibly fine if it is a bucket policy on a bucket named MYSITE.com, but is it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, it's better if I store my webpage in other service? I didn't know that they are not able to interpret PHP. Is theres a way to do this? Maybe installing a framework or library?

Comment: Well, it depends. AWS is great, because it provides low-level control over many implementation details of their services, but it may not be the best choice for every project. I would consider for example a docker container with php deployed in Fargate. But if all you want is to run your php service - any provider is a good option. AWS does make sense for example if you want to host many static files in s3 or if you want create some distributed background processes. The more complex your app is the more you can benefit from AWS.

Comment: Well, I chosed AWS because is really fast, I have the same site in bluehost and it is horrible and I pay so much monthly, that's why I am migrating my sites to AWS, I will try to put the server in AWS ECS and see if the file is working correctly, thanks so much for this anwser, I will update mine as soon as I make the changes